# MVC/Chart.js: Advanced Stacked Bar Chart with Line Chart

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm working on a MVC project and hit a snag on generating a chart in Chart.js. I'm trying to do a graph where the labels are the individuals and then do a stacked bar chart of the count per status (for each user) and then overlay a line graph of the total dollar amount per each user.

Here's an example of what the data looks like when it comes back from the stored procedure:

```
+-------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| User  |       Status        | Dollars | Count |
+-------+---------------------+---------+-------+
| Bob   | Thinking Of Selling | 2013.23 |    12 |
| Bob   | Currently Selling   | 1022.12 |     3 |
| Bob   | Going to Sell       |  103.71 |     2 |
| Suzy  | Currently Selling   | 4017.22 |    21 |
| Tom   | Thinking Of Selling | 1022.12 |     7 |
| Tom   | Going to Sell       | 3231.01 |    10 |
| Billy | Currently Selling   | 1012.39 |     5 |
| Billy | Thinking Of Selling | 1720.21 |     3 |
+-------+---------------------+---------+-------+
```

So the labels would be: Bob, Suzy, Tom, Billy and then (using Bob as the example) stack "Thinking Of Selling:12", "Currently Selling:3", "Going to Sell:2". Lastly, I would plot a line over Bob's column with a value of "3139.06". This would proceed down the line with each user getting a stacked column of the count of their statuses and a line plot of the sum dollar amount for their statuses.

I already have a different chart that does a bar chart with a line overlaid so I'm not too confused there. The problem I'm having (I think) has to do with matching the data to the labels. I'm thinking my data isn't formatted that makes it easy w/ Chart.js but I could be wrong.

Any thoughts on how to use the data below (as programmatic as possible) or how my data would need to be formatted to achieve the goal?

Comment: Do you want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JzWu.png) ?

Comment: @ℊααnd yup! Pretty much. Instead of the months, it would be the names. The "revenue", "expense", and "profit" stacks would be the various statuses. The line on that chart would be the sum of the dollar values for the statuses for that user (if that makes sense).

I saw examples of this but everything seemed so strongly typed or formatted. Where I was having trouble was the repeating username in the first column and then the fact that some users won't have some statuses (e.g. Suzy in the example). The status bit will be variable.

Comment: I'm not getting the data in JSON at the moment. It's currently coming from a stored procedure that is called in the Controller. The controller takes the data and generates comma delimited strings for each piece of data (ex: strMyReturnedUsernames = "'Bob','Suzzy','Tom','Billy'" and "strMyReturnedDollars = "2013.23,1022.12,103.71,4017.22,1022.12,3231.01,1012.39,1720.21"). It takes the strMyReturnedUsernames (and others) and puts it in the ViewBag  (ex: ViewBag.strMyReturnedUsernames) and then referenced in the View within the Chart.js dataset as "data: [@ViewBag.strMyReturnedUsernames]".